# Symfony/Doctrine: How to serialize an entity to a key value array

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

For some reason I want to serialize an entity to a simple key => value array without the related entites and with the real name of columns in the database. is there a way to that out of the box ? or should I make an entity serializer that uses the annotations to load columns names

Comment: You might use standard Serializer component if the property name instead of the column name is suitable for you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this might be a part of your solution.

```
    $reader = new AnnotationReader();


    $fieldNames = $em->getClassMetadata('AppBundle:Entity')->getFieldNames();
    foreach($fieldNames as $field){
        $reflClass = new \ReflectionProperty('AppBundle\Entity\Entity',$field);
        $classAnnotations = $reader->getPropertyAnnotations($reflClass);

        var_dump($classAnnotations[0]->name);
    }
```

[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.0/class-Doctrine.ORM.Mapping.Column.html)
[Doctrine Annotations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-common/en/latest/reference/annotations.html#usage)